# Send SMS from Web (are there some providers for this)?

Tags: sms, saas, sms-gateway

I'd like to have something like what the app.net site has. You click a button and get the option to send a link to your phone via SMS (or email). What are some options for implementing the sms side of things, and are there services or open source packages that provide this?

[Here's a random example from app.net](http://app.net/q99live) . Click the "Get this App" button to see what I mean.

Something like this would even work for me `<a href="http://saasSMS.com?url=mycorp.com/test.html">Send link to Phone</a>` Where "saasSMS.com" is some service that handles the whole sms side of things. Ideally could either handle that via a link or via a form post (and it would redirect back to your site on success or something).

**What I don't want**: A drop down that makes you pick your carrier and some php page that tries to email you @vtext.com or similar. That is just not slick enough.

Comment: If this is for yourself, your best bet might be to set up a Google or Yahoo acount, or use your Smartphone carrier.  If this is a web page for multiple users, the only thing I'm aware of is "Construct the e-mail address based on the carrier + phone #".  Sorry :(

Comment: We use CellTrust to send mass SMS messages to our users and it works well for us. Not sure if that's the exact kind of service you're looking for though.

Comment: this might be of interest: http://www.developershome.com/sms/sms_tutorial.asp?page=smsGateway

Comment: @paulsm4->it is for a web page for multiple users. That page you linked to mentioned this: http://www.kannel.org/ which might be promising, but seems like someone should already have that up and running and be able to provide a service to others.

Comment: You might need to use a third party service to send sms, something similar to grouptexting.com

Comment: @criticus--grouptexting.com looks like it has a decent solution, even if their website is a bit cheesy. They have an REST API you can use that takes JSON as input with phone number (or numbers), subject, and message body. Seems simple enough. They also have some support for international texting but I have to investigate that more.

Comment: There are many services providing SMS transport via HTTP or SMPP API. For example Clickatel or RouteSMS. For production I would recommend use SMPP connection and local Kannel (www.kannel.org) as gateway between SMSC and your web services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ViaNett HTTP API](http://www.vianett.com/en/developers/sms-api-overview/http-get-post-api) to send SMS messages worldwide without specifying the operator.

As long as your backend supports invoking HTTP requests it will work.

Here is an example written in PHP:

```php
<?php

// Register here to get a username and password:
// http://www.vianett.com/en/free-demonstration-account

if (vianett_sendsms('username', 'password', 'example', '+4412345678', 'Hello world', $error)) {
    echo 'Success!';
} else {
    echo $error;
}

function vianett_sendsms($username, $password, $from, $to, $msg, &$response=null) {
    $url = 'https://smsc.vianett.no/v3/send.ashx';
    $data = array(
        'user'  => $username,
        'pass'  => $password,
        'src'   => $from,
        'dst'   => $to,
        'msg'   => $msg
    );
    $qs = http_build_query($data);
    $response = file_get_contents($url.'?'.$qs);
    return $response == '200|OK';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We're getting good results from http://www.twilio.com

Answer (score 0):

For direct SMS, you can try contacting a service provider and make a contract with it. If its for small projects and the server is accessible, you could put a GPRS mobile phone or modem and send with it.