# Can Twilio send an SMS that will be free of carrier charges to a US user?

Tags: sms, twilio

In the U.S, carriers normally [charge people](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-US-carriers-charge-for-incoming-calls-and-text-messages) for receiving SMS messages (It's not like other countries where only the side that sends the SMS is charged).

Can I send an SMS with Twilio (or with another service) that will be free for the end users to receive? I am happy to pay the cost instead of the end user, of course.

Twilio's [pricing](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183228-How-does-Twilio-s-pricing-work-) and [U.S pricing](https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/us) pages don't have anything about this.

I can't find any [other](https://www.clickatell.com/promotions/united-states-text-messaging/) [good](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=sms%20saas%20united%20states) [service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273237/send-sms-from-web-are-there-some-providers-for-this) that seems to solve this problem either.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found your answer here: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133527-Do-mobile-users-get-charged-when-they-send-messages-to-Twilio-US-toll-free-numbers-

From the article:

> #### Do mobile users get charged when they send messages to Twilio US toll-free numbers?
>
> Yes, they will be charged according to their mobile texting plan. Subscribers who pay a monthly charge for unlimited two-way texting will not be charged extra for texting to a toll-free number, but other subscribers may be charged per text sent or received.
>
> Calls to toll free numbers, on the other hand, are always free for the callers.

Get started here: https://www.twilio.com/sms/toll-free